# string replace phone number iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsstring, import-contacts

I import a phone-number  from "Contacts" and save in `NSString`.
this string contains white-space and I try to delete them using the method:

```
numero = numero.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

this method doesn't work.

---

```
func sostituisci( stringa: NSString! ) -> NSString     
{         
var numero: NSString = ""         
NSLog(stringa) 
numero = ((stringa as String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") as NSString) 
NSLog(numero)

return numero
}
```

the output unchanged

---

log

```
2014-11-05 17:54:50.734 HappyRicarica[33438:3119446] (327) 124-3503
2014-11-05 17:54:50.737 HappyRicarica[33438:3119446] (327) 124-3503
```

Comment: For the record, Foundation's types are different from Swift's Types. A `String` in Swift is not an `NSString`

Comment: What happens when "it doesn't work?"  Is the string unchanged?  Do you get an error?  This worked fine for me with `numero` declared as either `String` or `NSString`.  Is `numero` declared with `var` or `let` ?

Comment: the string unchanged.

Comment: numero is declared var

Comment: option-click on `numero`.  What does it say?  Also, could you show us the value of `numero` before you try to change it?

Comment: method
[code]
   func sostituisci( stringa: NSString! ) -> NSString
    {
        var numero: NSString = ""
        NSLog(stringa)
        numero = ((stringa as String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") as NSString)
        NSLog(numero)
        return numero
    }
[/code]

Comment: log: 2014-11-05 17:24:03.212 HappyRicarica[33274:3108083] (327) 124-3503
2014-11-05 17:24:03.213 HappyRicarica[33274:3108083] (327) 124-3503

Comment: update your question with the code and output from the above comments.  It is hard to read in comments.

Comment: So if you call `sostituisci(" 1 2 3 4 5 ")` you are saying that both `NSLogs` are the same?

Comment: update the question whit log.

Comment: if try whit "sostituisci(" 1 2 3 4 5 "), the method is true

Comment: Why as you saving the number in an NSString in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the space character in your string is not really a space.  Try adding this after `NSLog(string)` to see what the unicode scalar values are for the characters in your string:

```
for uni in (stringa as String).unicodeScalars {
    println("\(uni) = \(uni.value)")
}
```

The expected output for "(327) 124-3503" is:

```
( = 40
3 = 51
2 = 50
7 = 55
) = 41
  = 32
1 = 49
2 = 50
4 = 52
- = 45
3 = 51
5 = 53
0 = 48
3 = 51
```

From your comment, your space has value 160 instead of 32.  You could remove that with:

```
numero = stringa.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(String(Character(UnicodeScalar(160))), withString: "")
```

Comment: the log when I use your method:

HappyRicarica[33497:3132714] (327) 124-3503
( = 40
3 = 51
2 = 50
7 = 55
) = 41
  = 160
1 = 49
2 = 50
4 = 52
- = 45
3 = 51
5 = 53
0 = 48
3 = 51

Comment: I know you aleady accepted an answer.  I just wanted you to know why your original code wasn't working.  Your space wasn't really a space (ASCII 32) but it had a value of 160 instead.  See the update above with how to replace that.  The answer you accepted is really nice, so I'd leave that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
extension String {
    var numbersOnly: String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890")
            .invertedSet)
            .joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    var numbersExempt: String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890"))
            .joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    var charactersOnly: String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ").invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    var charactersExempt: String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    func keep(keepIt: String) -> String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: keepIt).invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    func exclude(excludeIt: String) -> String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: excludeIt)).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
}

let phoneNumber = "+1 (555) 555 - 5555".numbersOnly
print(phoneNumber) // "15555555555"

let excludePlusMinus = "+1 (555) 555-5555".exclude("+-") // "1 (555) 5555555"
let keepWhatever = "+1 (555) 555-5555".keep("()-+") //  "+()-"
```

you can also use your function to subtract only spaces with some adjustments. Try like this:

```
func sostituisci(stringa: String) -> String {
     return stringa.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
}

sostituisci("1 234 567 8901")   // "12345678901"
```

or like an extension:

```
extension String {
    var sostituisci: String {
        return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    }
}
let phoneNumber2 = "1 234 567 8901".sostituisci
```

Comment: Upvoted, very helpful in understanding the power of componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet.

Answer (score 0):

did you try :

```
let str = "XX XX XX XX XX"
    let separated = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    let finalStr = "".join(separated)
```

Comment: error in line:
let finalStr = "".join(separated)   -> "'String' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Comment: if you replace `let finalStr = "".join(separated)` with `let finalStr = ("" as String).join(separated)` ?

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` is not `String`, so you should use:

```
numero = ((numero as String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") as NSString)
```