# eliminate spaces in array it is not working swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I get the number from a matrix contacts ,which each one have a number of the persone, however my problem is that I want the number in raw in order to I can match with another matrix.

```
       for a in contacts 

{
        let content: String = a.phone

        let result1 = content.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString:"")
        let result2 = result1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString:"")
        let result3 = result2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString:"")
        let result4 = result3.replace(" ", replacement: "")




        println(result4)


       // newNames.append(result4)
      //contador=contador+1
    }
   //result[555 555,999 3188,999 1]
```

so is not eliminate the spaces why?, why if the other conditions worked well,  I also use the:

```
let result4 = result3.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

and it does not work why?

//result[555 555,999 3188,999 1]

Comment: Your space character might not actually be a space.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26763932/1630618

Comment: thank you very much!!! its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a different API, `replace()`.

Use the working API, `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString()` instead.

#### Chaining

Note that you can chain in Swift, which is much more elegant.

```
let cleanNumber = content
  .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString:"")
  .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString:"")
  .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString:"")
  .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString:"")
```

#### Filter and map

Also, be aware of the even more concise `filter` and `map` APIs.

```
let content = "(459) 333-4938"
let cleanNumber = content.characters.filter {
    ![" ", "-", "(", ")"].contains($0)
}.map { String($0) }.joinWithSeparator("")
// "4593334938"
```

#### NSCharacterSet

And the old `NSCharacterSet` trick:

```
let illegal = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890").invertedSet
let cleanNumber = content
   .componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(illegal)
   .joinWithSeparator("")
// "4593334938"
```

Comment: The OP did say that he tried `let result4 = result3.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")` and it didn't work.

Comment: Thats true I used the: "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString()" and it does not work

Comment: Yes, but from the posted code I infer that OP did not use that function.

Comment: Actually I have used "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
" and it does not work too.

Comment: Yes, trimming only works at the end. My code above works - tested in Playground.

Comment: @Mundi You are assuming that the white space is the space character 0x20, it may not be. Your code is not working with the OP's string.

Answer (score -1):

You could try extending `String` to include a function for removing a list of characters.

For Swift 1.2 (not 2):

```
extension String {
    func removeCharacters(chars: [Character]) -> String {
        return String(filter(self) {find(chars, $0) == nil})
    }
}

let chars: [Character] = ["(", ")", "-", " "]

let result = content.removeCharacters(chars)
```

Comment: May I ask, why the downvotes?

Comment: Try it in Swift 2, there is an error: Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(String, (Character) -> Bool)'

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out, I haven't really been using 2.0 yet, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Swift 2.0 is imminent, Xcode GM is available. I am already seeing my Swift 1.x answers being down-voted because they are incorrect for 2.0. It s going to be a real pain to find all my Swift answers and adding 2.0 answers.